# injectivity of holomorphic function based on its restriction

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be holomorphic on $\mathbb D$ . Suppose there is an annulus {$z : 0 < r < |z| < 1$} in $\mathbb D$ such that $f$ restricted to this annulus is one-to-one.Show that $f$ is one-to-one on $\mathbb D$.

(Source: - Gamelin, Chapter 8)

N.B. :- I couldn't arrive at the solution using the hint given there. So, I am posting it here.

Thank You!

Comment: Is $\mathbb{D}$ the unit disk $\{ z \in \mathbb{C}:|z| <1\}$?

Comment: Yes !! @  Crostul.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/210396/a-holomorphic-function-f-injective-on-partial-d-must-be-injective-in-ba).

Comment: Sorry...may be a possible duplicate..  but instead of something topological solution, I think Open Mapping Theorem or something like that is to be used, since this is a problem from the Complex Analysis book by Gamelin. I am looking for that solution using those theories.