# Show that if f restricted to circle is injective, then $f$ is injective on closed unit ball

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose that $f$ is a Holomorphic function defined on an open set U of the complex plane containing $cl(B(0, 1))$. Let $S^1 = {z ∈ C : |z| = 1} = ∂B(0, 1)$.

Show that if $f(S^1)$ is an ellipse and f restricted on $S^1$ is injective, then $f$ is injective on $cl(B(0, 1))$.

I have a hint to apply the argument principle to $f(z) − w_0$ for $w_0 ∈ C$

I feel as though it may be similar to this thread: [A holomorphic function $f$, injective on $\partial D$, must be injective in $\bar{D}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/210396/a-holomorphic-function-f-injective-on-partial-d-must-be-injective-in-ba)

However, I'm not sure why we are told extra information such as $f(S^1)$ is an ellipse. Would that change the question? I'm worried that I have completely the wrong idea.
Can someone please also provide me a proof of the injective part? I'm struggling to understand and it would be highly appreciated, since I've been researching for the last two hours but with not any success.

Comment: your question is a duplicate of your link (though I suggest reading: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/744812/one-one-analytic-functions-on-unit-disc ) *if you are going to use Jordan Curve Theorem*.  The information that $f(S^1)$ is an ellipse may allow you to bypass JCT.

Comment: @user8675309 Ah I thought so. How would I prove the injective part please?

Comment: @user8675309 Can I also ask why I can skip the Jordan Curve Theorem part sorry?

Comment: The primary result you need is that a Jordan Curve has a winding number modulus of $1$ for all points in the bounded component ('interior') of its complement (then apply Argument Principle).  The fact $f(S^1)$ is an ellipse tells you a ton of information -- i.e. there are two components to the complement of $f(S^1)$ and this allows direct winding number calculation (e.g. suppose $0$ is in the bounded component and then homotopy to $S^1$ ).  Please read my suggested link -- there was less than 4 minutes between my comment and your follow up question so you did not digest it before commenting.